# How to Fix Virtual Attributes Error in Select Query Rails when add "1 as variable"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

When I want to be this query:

```
Documentos.select("estaciones, 1 as totalPruebas, 1 as totalFilas, 1 as totalPreguntas, '' as nombreColegio").where("id = #{idUsuario}").order("estaciones")
```

i had this result:

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «as» LINE 1:
>   SELECT COUNT(estaciones, 1 as totalPruebas, 1 as totalFila...
>                                        ^

```
: SELECT COUNT(estaciones, 1 as totalPruebas, 1 as totalFilas, 1 as totalPreguntas, '' as nombreColegio") FROM "documentos"
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to add additional null attributes because i have to use them to precalculate elements in other queries that modify them after

Comment: Perhaps you need to add more info. to your question.

Comment: mmm How i can add null virtual attributes to select query rails? can be this the question... thank you!

Comment: I'm not pretty sure, but what you're trying can't be done with COALESCE and NULLIF in Postgres? What's that precalculation you need to do?

Comment: I have to migrate .find_by_sql queries how: "select 1 as variable, test.station from station" to rails normal querys with .select .where. etc

Answer (score 0):

When i want to use "as" to rename column, add a count but i only be Terminales.select("estaciones as nombreEstacion")

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «as»
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(terminales.*, estacion as test) AS count_termin...
                                            ^
: SELECT COUNT(terminales.*, estacion as test) AS count_terminales_all_estacion_as_test, "terminales"."id" AS terminales_id FROM "terminales" GROUP BY "terminales"."id"

thanks!

Comment: This must be part of your question. You can edit it.